# Weird power/shutdown behaviour with a windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, power, shutdown, hibernate

I've got a Windows 10 Pro Dell Latitude e7440. I'm having a few power issues, which appear to have something to do with shutting down.

### Full Description

Every time I hibernate my laptop, and turn it on *without*  plugging it in/unplugging it from the adapter, and turn it on a few hours later, it all works fine, with the laptop booting up as it should after hibernation.

However, whenever I unplug/plug it in *after* hibernating, then it shuts down, or doesn't load from `hiberfile.sys`, meaning that I lose many interactive command prompts and similar - this is a problem as I'm a developer.

I've tried everything I could find, purging the `hiberfile.sys`, and running power troubleshooter, and still the problem won't go away.

Can anybody think of a solution to this?

Comment: I read your post a few times and it still doesn’t make sense to me. Please [edit] your post and clarify what exactly you are doing and what exactly happens. Terms like “it shuts down” does not properly describe a specific scenario. I can think of several ways a laptop “shuts down.”

Comment: @Appleoddity done

Comment: Have you looked in the Windows event log to see if there are any related events? Are you sure the system isn’t turning back on at some point after you plug it in or unplug it? Maybe try pulling the battery. You don’t really indicate if it is a transition from plugged/unplugged that causes the problem, or if plugged/unplugged/plugged would still cause an issue?

Comment: Both and all... I forgot to mention that it also turns on whenever I plug in the power cable - or turns from hibernation to sleep to be accurate. I'll check the logs.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm generating _loads_ of unusual events - the most relevant code is probably 41

Comment: Right I've checked some docs and tried something Microsoft recommends about err code `41`, and I'll come back if it fails.

Comment: The system turning on when you plug it in is a BIOS setting. I would recommend downloading “Dell command update.” Let it update your BIOS and drivers. You might also try resetting your BIOS to defaults. Have you been in there changing settings? Latitude is a business machine. Is this system managed by your place of work? In any case you need to [edit] your post and include all of this relevant information you have posted in comments including better details about the events you saw in the event log which clearly show it is not transitioning power states properly.

Comment: @Appleoddity it's my laptop - I'm freelance. I've already tried with support assist, but will have a look at the BIOS. And no, I haven't messed with any settings... I'll edit the question ltr.